# Left join not working with Where statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

```
select a.Postcode,b.Adres
from Colliers_DataAnalytics.conversie_PC_BU_GM_COROP a
left join Colliers_DataAnalytics.Coordinaten_Adres b 
on (b.Adres like concat(a.Postcode, '%'));
```

This statement works well, but when I add where statement at the end, it doesn't work. someone help me.

```
select a.Postcode,b.Adres
from Colliers_DataAnalytics.conversie_PC_BU_GM_COROP a
left join Colliers_DataAnalytics.Coordinaten_Adres b 
on (b.Adres like concat(a.Postcode, '%'))
where a.Postcode = '4706KG';
```

But if I use other column instead Postcode, it works.

Comment: are you sure that you have a record that has Postcode = '4706KG' ?

Comment: what do you mean by not working? you mean you get no records at all or no data from Colliers_DataAnalytics.Coordinaten_Adres table?

Comment: Not working mean? Did get error? Please detail your question and if there are error show the log error

Comment: @asmgx  @ dwir182 I use MySQL Workbench to query, it run forever without result.

Comment: There is a bug in mySQL Workbench that it sometimes does not show results at all.. close it and reopen it

Comment: I have closed and reopen many times, but still doesn't work

Comment: what is the error that you are getting, what exactly the problem is?

Comment: message is still "running", but it run forever and I get no result

Comment: if I remove where statement, result show immediately

Comment: You got an index on `postcode`? If not put one on it and try again.

Comment: @ sticky bit yes, I  got an index on postcode.

Comment: if use other column instead of Postcode, it works